# How to use input variables on the same page while making an SQL query?

Tags: php, html

I have an input field which takes user address and then calculates its longitude and latitude.
I have a database of stored addresses with their respective longitudes and latitudes.
I am making the following SQL query to compare the entered address in input field with the database addresses to find the nearest locations:

```
 $sql4 = 'SELECT
     (ATAN(
         SQRT(
             POW(COS(RADIANS(maptable.latitude)) *
                 SIN(RADIANS(maptable.longitude) -
                     RADIANS(wishLongitude)), 2) +
             POW(COS(RADIANS(wishLatitude)) *
                 SIN(RADIANS(maptable.latitude)) -
                 SIN(RADIANS(wishLatitude)) *
                 cos(RADIANS(maptable.latitude)) *
                 cos(RADIANS(maptable.longitude) -
                     RADIANS(wishLongitude)), 2)
         ),
         SIN(RADIANS(wishLatitude)) *
         SIN(RADIANS(maptable.latitude)) +
         COS(RADIANS(wishLatitude)) *
         COS(RADIANS(maptable.latitude)) *
         COS(RADIANS(maptable.longitude) -
             RADIANS(wishLongitude))
     ) * 6371000) as distance,
     maptable.id, maptable.price, maptable.owner, maptable.myaddress, maptable.phone
 FROM maptable
 ORDER BY distance ASC
 LIMIT 15 ';
 $result = $mysqli - > query($sql4);
```

And a input field on the same page in which user enters their address:

```
 <form method='post' id='wishInput' >
                   <input class='form-control' id='autocomplete' placeholder='Enter your address' onFocus='geolocate()' name='myaddress' type='text'></input>
                   <input  name='wishLatitude' id='wishLatitude' >
                   <input  name='wishLongitude' id='wishLongitude'  />
                   <input type='submit' name='wishSubmit'>
                   </form>
```

**How I can use *"wishLongitude"* and *"wishLatitude"* variables in the query???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if( $_REQUEST['wishSubmit'] )
{
    $wishLatitude = $_REQUEST['wishLatitude'];
    $wishLongitude = $_REQUEST['wishLongitude'];

    $sql4 = "SELECT
     (ATAN(
         SQRT(
             POW(COS(RADIANS(maptable.latitude)) *
                 SIN(RADIANS(maptable.longitude) -
                     RADIANS($wishLongitude)), 2) +
             POW(COS(RADIANS($wishLatitude)) *
                 SIN(RADIANS(maptable.latitude)) -
                 SIN(RADIANS($wishLatitude)) *
                 cos(RADIANS(maptable.latitude)) *
                 cos(RADIANS(maptable.longitude) -
                     RADIANS($wishLongitude)), 2)
         ),
         SIN(RADIANS($wishLatitude)) *
         SIN(RADIANS(maptable.latitude)) +
         COS(RADIANS($wishLatitude)) *
         COS(RADIANS(maptable.latitude)) *
         COS(RADIANS(maptable.longitude) -
             RADIANS($wishLongitude))
     ) * 6371000) as distance,
     maptable.id, maptable.price, maptable.owner, maptable.myaddress, maptable.phone
     FROM maptable
     ORDER BY distance ASC
     LIMIT 15 ";
     $result = $mysqli - > query($sql4);
}
```

You've to enclosed your query with `"` So that the php variables can be used inside the query.

Comment: Worked well! :)